# Prevent Zoom.us pop up "Get an app for 'zoommtg' link"

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, hyperlink, microsoft-store

Every time I join a Zoom meeting, this pops up. (Get an app to open this 'zoommtg' link

I don't want to install the Zoom app but always join from the web browser.
Can I prevent this window pop up?

[image: zoom Microsoft store]

The OS in Windows 11.
The web browser is Google Chrome 110.0.5563.64

**What I have tried**

I tried to set the default app for opening .zoommtg link to Google Chrome rather than Zoom app.
After setting as the below screenshot, however, it still try to open Zoom Windows app when I click the 'Launch meeting' button.

[image: default app zoommtg chrome]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Firefox open Zoom URLs using Zoom application](https://superuser.com/questions/1343020/how-to-configure-firefox-open-zoom-urls-using-zoom-application)

Comment: Related [How to choose which application Chrome uses for deep links (e.g. when zoom:823948290348 is typed into Chrome's URI bar)?](https://superuser.com/q/1642801/152004)

Comment: Please review the above links carefully, if none of the above help you,please [edit] the question, share what you have tried what you have found and why it didn't meet your needs. Also add more details like name and version of the web browser that you are using and the steps tht you follow that cause the pop up to appear.

Comment: Regarding "Ruben's link didn't help because the linked article is about Linux." I don't know to what link you are referring to. The [first one](https://superuser.com/q/1343020/152004) points to a question having 5 answers. While the top answer is about configuring Firefox in Gnome the there are others for different operating systems incluing Windows.  The [second link](https://superuser.com/q/1642801/152004) points a question with one answer about Chrome for Windows, more specifically suggest to edit a specific Windows registry key.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but I can't show the image in a comment.

I don't think you can do what you are trying.  Because Chrome does not know how to handle the **.zoom** or **.zoommtg** files.  If you don't want that popup then (like me) you can install zoom.  But then you get a different popup like this (even when clicking on a URL).

You can get rid of that by ticking the checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: I know, what I am suggesting is that there is no reprieve even if you install the app.

Answer (score 0):

Open registry editor

Right click on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT", New > Key

rename to "zoommtg" (**no dot** since its a protocol not a filetype)

Right click on "zoommtg", New > String value

Rename to "URL Protocol"

Additionally i wrote the following javascript that lets you see the "Join from Your Browser" button:

```js
let jfyb = ("<h3 class=\"rm-presentation\"><span>Having issues with Zoom Client? <a web_client=\"\" tabindex=\"0\" role=\"button\">Join from Your Browser</a></span></h3>")
let buttons
let tries = 1
let intervalBtn = setInterval(tryGetButtons, 10)
function tryGetButtons(){
    if(++tries > 1000) clearInterval(intervalBtn)
    if(buttons == undefined) { 
        buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("pUmU_FLW")[0]
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalBtn)
        if(!buttons.innerHTML.includes(jfyb))
            buttons.innerHTML += jfyb
    }
}
```

You can use this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld to add it to the https://zoom.us/j/ site.

I also added this css:

```
body{
    filter: invert(1) !important;   
    background-color: black;
}
```

to prevent the eye burning white of the join meeting page.

Hope this helps.